# ¿Por qué no me funcionan los col en BS?

Tags: html, css, progressbar

Estoy trabajando en front-end pero no me funcionan las col.
Quisiera que los circulos queden: 3 uno al lado del otro y abajo otros 3.
El problema es que las col no se separan y quedan los circulos muy cerca y sin ocupar el ancho de la pagina.

```
    <div class="row">
    <h1>Hard and soft skills</h1>
    <!-- 1er circulo -->
    <circle-progress
    [percent]="85"
    [radius]="60"
    [showUnits]="false"
    [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
    [innerStrokeWidth]="1"
    [outerStrokeColor]="'#3414EB'"
    [innerStrokeColor]="'#070129'"
    [animation]="true"
    [animationDuration]="300"
  ></circle-progress>

    <!-- 2do circulo -->
    <circle-progress
    [percent]="85"
    [radius]="60"
    [showUnits]="false"
    [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
    [innerStrokeWidth]="1"
    [outerStrokeColor]="'#3414EB'"
    [innerStrokeColor]="'#070129'"
    [animation]="true"
    [animationDuration]="300"
    ></circle-progress>

    <!-- 3er circulo -->
    <circle-progress
    [percent]="85"
    [radius]="100"
    [showUnits]="false"
    [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
    [innerStrokeWidth]="1"
    [outerStrokeColor]="'#3414EB'"
    [innerStrokeColor]="'#070129'"
    [animation]="true"
    [animationDuration]="300"
    ></circle-progress>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
    <!-- 1er circulo -->
    <circle-progress
    [percent]="85"
    [radius]="100"
    [showUnits]="false"
    [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
    [innerStrokeWidth]="1"
    [outerStrokeColor]="'#3414EB'"
    [innerStrokeColor]="'#070129'"
    [animation]="true"
    [animationDuration]="300"
  ></circle-progress>

    <!-- 2do circulo -->
    <circle-progress
    [percent]="85"
     [radius]="100"
    [showUnits]="false"
    [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
    [innerStrokeWidth]="1"
    [outerStrokeColor]="'#3414EB'"
    [innerStrokeColor]="'#070129'"
    [animation]="true"
    [animationDuration]="300"
   ></circle-progress>
   </div>
```

También probé poniendo cada código de cada circulo dentro de un div `class="row"` diferente y poner dentro de ese **div otro div** con el `class: "col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"` pero siguen viéndose uno abajo de otro.

Comment: De hecho que los _col_ deben estar dentro de un _row_. ¿Está el _row_ en un _container_?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que usas bootstrap, aunque no lo mencionas.

Si es así, dentro de cada row (fila) debes poner un div con la clase col **siempre** para que boostrap funcione bien.

Si quieres ponerlo en una línea, sería así:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    Contenido
   </div>
</div>
```

En tu caso, sabiendo que el grid de bootstrap es de 12 columnas, y sabiendo que quieres dividirlo en tres partes, deberias ponerlo así:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Contenido
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Contenido2
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Contenido3
   </div>
</div>
```

Y finalmente, si quieres otra línea similar, tan solo hace falta que la pongas a continuación del mismo modo dentro de su fila (row) así:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Contenido
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Contenido2
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Contenido3
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Contenido4
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Contenido5
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Contenido6
   </div>
</div>
```

Inténtalo cambiando los **Contenidox** por tus circulos a ver si ahora si que te funciona. Recuerda que debes cargar el bootstrap para ello antes, claro.

### Ejemplo funcional completo:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      Contenido
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      Contenido2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      Contenido3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      Contenido4
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      Contenido5
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      Contenido6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```